# How can I add an additional json parent node when mapping a DTO?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, dto, mapstruct

I'm working on some data product mapping, and I stumbled across an issue I'm not sure how to solve.
Suppose I have a `HumanMood` data product. I'm receiving pushed data (`HumanMoodInputDto`) through a POST request method received by WebFlux controller.
The `HumanMoodInputDto` DTO:

```
@Data
public class HumanMoodInputDto {

    @JsonProperty("human_mood")
    @NotNull(message = "Human mood can't be null ")
    private String humanMood;

    @JsonProperty("last_update")
    @Pattern(regexp = "([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})", message = "Date format must be YYYY-MM-DD")
    @NotNull(message = "Last update can't be null ")
    private String lastUpdate;
}
```

I'm using `MapStruct` to map the data product. And the response that my controller is returning is based on this `HumanMoodOutputDto`:

```
@Data
@JsonRootName(value = "data")
public class HumanMoodOutputDto {

    @JsonProperty("human_mood")
    private String humanMood;

    @JsonProperty("last_update")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate lastUpdate;

    @JsonProperty("updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;
}
```

The `@PostMapping` for `WebFlux` controller:

```
@PostMapping("humanMood")
public Mono<HumanMoodOutputDto> getHumanMood(
    @Valid @RequestBody
    Mono<HumanMoodInputDto> humanMoodInputDto) {
        return humanMoodService.create(humanMoodInputDto.map(mapper::dtoToPushedInput))
            .map(mapper::outputToDto);
}
```

So at the moment I'm getting  response that looks like this:

```
{
   "data":{
      "human_mood":"good",
      "last_update":"2021-08-19",
      "update_by":null
   }
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to add an additional json parent node called "data_flags", which would hold `ArrayList<String>` values, that would describe any errors or warnings when mapping the data. So in the end I want my output to look like this:

```
{
   "data":{
      "human_mood":"good",
      "last_update":"2021-08-19",
      "update_by":null
   }
   "data_flags":[
      
   ]
}
```

Should I create a seperate DTO and then another one which which would contain data from both of them, or is there a more simple way to enrichen the data product?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way in my opinion is to build a separate DTO that would have the following attributes:

```
private HumanMoodOutputDto data;

@JsonProperty("data_flags")
private HumanMoodMappingWarningOutputDto dataFlags;
```

This would allow you to get rid of `@JsonRootName(value = "data")` in `HumanMoodOutputDto`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for tor the reply! I've got it working, although wondering how and where logic should be coded regarding the data_flags, for example, if humanMood was inputed as null, how do I set some kind of a value for the data_flags?

Comment: But in that case Spring will answer back on your behalf because you are using `@Valid` and `@NotNull` annotations. The only reason for the existance of `data_flags` is if you need some rather complex logic to validate and map the received data. In that case that could be done in the Service that your Controller would call, which in your case seems to be `HumanMoodService`.